# Remove query strings only from specific URL's in htaccess (Apache)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

Currently I am trying to remove query strings from multiple different URL's.

What I am using at the moment to remove "?cp=true" is

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?cp=true\sHTTP [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI} [L,R,QSD]
```

However this removes that query string from all pages with that query string. I want to only target a specific page e.g.

(/folder/another-folder/this-page)

Another change I would prefer to do, however not essential is to be able to remove any query string and not just "?cp=true". How would I go about doing this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to only target a specific page e.g.`/folder/another-folder/this-page`

In that case you can include this URL in your `RewriteCond` before `?`:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /folder/another-folder/this-page\?cp=true\sHTTP [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=302,NE,QSD]
```

If you want to remove all query strings then use:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /folder/another-folder/this-page\? [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=302,NE,QSD]
```

Comment: Many thanks, that worked perfectly. One more question, I have URL's with only a ? in front of the URL. How would I go about removing the single question mark. An example URL is: /folder/another-folder/this-page? 

How can I change this to just "/folder/another-folder/this-page"

Comment: I have edited 2nd rule. It will take care of empty `?` as well.